# обвертка как в твиттер

Tags: twitter, css

[image]

Как сделать такую же обвертку на css, как например в твиттере, смотрел у них в css, ничего не понял... (

Comment: Про какую "обвертку" вы говорите? Имеете в виду **обёртку** для поля формы?

Comment: да, именно

Comment: вот эту светло-голубую?

Comment: да, в твиттере он еще на стеклянный похож

Answer (score 1):

Варианта два: либо вложить один div в другой, у большого будет голубой фон, у маленького белый, либо просто границу сделать нужного цвета.

Answer (score 0):

Способы разные есть: с использованием графики и без нёё на CSS. [Вот тут два примера](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SXESy/) на CSS. Первый вариант - иконка карандаша на кнопке submit, второй вариант - иконка в самом текстовом поле.

Comment: нет, вы не поняли вопроса, я выше описал

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение!

```
.glass_block{
padding: 20px;
background: rgb(204,204,204); /* для не поддерживающих rgba */
background: rgba(204,204,204,0.6); /* для нормальных браузеров */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60); /* для родного IE */
zoom: 1; /* затычка для IE */
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
border-radius: 15px; /* радиус для нормальных браузеров */
-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* для Gecko браузеров */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* для Webkit браузеров */
-khtml-border-radius: 15px; /* для KDE браузеров */
```

}

Comment: как теперь достичь 90% прозрачности?

Comment: Измените параметры на:

    background: rgba(204,204,204,0.9);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90);

Comment: а в rgb обычном как задается прозрачность?

Comment: @foozzi, в rgb никак. На то есть rgba

Comment: а существуют еще браузеры не поддерживающие rgba?

Comment: или как сделать кроссбраузерность в без rgba на прозрачность?